# How to conditionally change email content from Webform submissions

Tags: 7, webforms, emails

[Reading the docs](https://www.drupal.org/node/273806) I can see that you can conditionally change the recipient of a webform email based on a field value, but that's not quite what I want to do. I want to modify the *content* of the message based on a form input. For example, based on a webform field like:

**Favorite Color:**
[] Blue  [] Yellow  [] Red

Upon submission the user should receive totally different email messages saying either:

> You probably like the sky...

or

> You probably like bananas...

etc. (you get the idea).

Note: it would be clever and would solve this minimalistic example to create the options like

```
the sky|Blue
bananas|Yellow
```

and then use their tokens, but that's not an option in this case as it's multiple paragraphs of text I want to be different in the conditional messages.

Comment: Maybe this module could be usefull : https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rules

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a coding solution but you could implement [hook_webform_submission_presave()](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21webform%21webform.api.php/function/hook_webform_submission_presave/7) in a custom module and use that to save the appropriate text to a hidden webform field type, then see if the token for that field will work in the email.

Alternatively, you could implement [hook_webform_submission_insert()](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21webform%21webform.api.php/function/hook_webform_submission_insert/7) and send the email programmatically there, which would give you full conditional control of the email recipients and contents.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this, but looking to do the same I hope to go with

http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21webform%21templates%21webform-mail.tpl.php/7

That is, write your own webform-mail-[nid].tpl.php and have php logic there.

Answer (score 0):

in drupal 8 it can be set in the handlers parameters

```
/admin/structure/webform/manage/contact/handlers
```